# Ag-grid. Change Row Color After Cell Value Is Changed

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When a cell is updated, I would like the row to change color.

I have been able to update the cell color but not the row color

```
      onCellValueChanged: function(params) {
        if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
          params.colDef.cellStyle = function(params) {
            return { backgroundColor: 'green' };
          };
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gridOptions.getRowStyle = function(params) {
   if (params.node.rowIndex === 'the index of row you want to change color ') {
      return { background: 'red' }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more description of your answer.

Comment: Use 'gridOptions.getRowStyle' to give style to the row, change the if condition according to your case.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, it is possible to provide to the grid a `cellFlashDelay` and `cellFadeDelay` to configure the behavior when a cell flash for cells that has a column definition sets with `enableCellChangeFlash: true`.

For your particular case where you want specific **row** to be selected you can select the row desired by index and call the `flashCells` function which also allow provide the fade delay and flash delay.

```
// Add this in your event to flash:
const row = gridRef.current.api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0);
gridRef.current!.api.flashCells({
      rowNodes: [row],
      flashDelay: 5000,
      fadeDelay: 1000,
});

//...
const gridRef = useRef<AgGridReact>(null);
<AgGridReact
    ref={gridRef}
/>
```

For the style, you can override the css variable `--ag-value-change-value-highlight-background-color`. However, that is limited to the background color and not the foreground color. Hence, you can override the CSS using `.ag-cell.ag-cell-not-inline-editing.ag-cell-normal-height.ag-cell-value.ag-cell-data-changed` and set the `color` and `background-color`